# No Route Matching in rails 6 for multiple route parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jrubyonrails

routes.rb:

```
get '/get_text_by_tablenum/:filename_id/:tablenum_id', to: 'dashboard#get_text_by_tablenum'
```

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      cache: false,
      url: '/get_text_by_tablenum/' + filename + '/' + id_value_string,
      timeout: 5000,
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, errorTextStatus, error) {
       alert("Failed to submit : " + errorTextStatus + " ;" + error);

      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)


      }
```

rake routes:

```
GET /get_text_by_tablenum/:filename_id/:tablenum_id(.:format)  dashboard#get_text_by_tablenum
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
No route matches [GET] "/get_text_by_tablenum/MPLX_1Q20_Conf_Call_Slides.pdf/12"
```

any thoughts on why I'm getting this error message?

Comment: strange, I just had to reverse the order :filename_id and :tablenum_id to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple your resource must be at the end of the URL.
`MPLX_1Q20_Conf_Call_Slides.pdf` it is a file and not a path.

**example**:

```
get "path/to/file.pdf", to: "my_controller#action"`
```

The dot was removed because it is used as a separator for formatted routes. If you need to use a dot within an :filename add a constraint. `constraints: { filename: /.*/ }`

Now your routes look like this:

```
  get 'files/:filename', to: "files#index", constraints: { filename: /.*/ }
```

then in browser:
http://localhost:3000/files/MPLX_1Q20_Conf_Call_Slides.pdf

**files_controller.rb**

```
app/controllers/files_controller.rb
    1: class FilesController < ApplicationController
    2:   def index
    3:     byebug
=>  4:     filename = params[:filename]
    5:     send_file("#{Rails.root}/private/#{filename}",
    6:           :filename => "#{filename}",
    7:           :type => "application/pdf", #for example if pdf
    8:           :disposition => 'inline')
    9:   end
   10: end
(byebug) params
<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"files", "action"=>"index", "filename"=>"MPLX_1Q20_Conf_Call_Slides.pdf"} permitted: false>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. that's the solution. related, any idea why the .pdf extension gets removed from "params[:filename_id]" from within the controller?

Comment: The dot was removed because it is used as a separator for formatted routes. If you need to use a dot within an :filename add a constraint. constraints: { filename: /.*/ }